# From where do I call different services (controller or directly in the service)?

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, architecture

I have an architecture question about my Laravel application. I have the entity post. Then I use the spatie package `"spatie/laravel-tags":"^4.3"`. When I want to create a post I send my request against the Laravel interface. The route forwards to the controller. The controller forwards the request body *(the form data)* to the PostService. The PostService forwards the data to the PostRepository. The repository creates the new post and returns it to the service. Now I want to attach the tags to the post. My question. Do I call the TagService in the PostService? Or should the PostController do that?

Comment: I believe it is a good approach for using events

Comment: Controllers in MVC architecture should play the role of routing to the logic, that's why I believe you should do it in the controller and not in the service

Comment: I also think you should not pass the request from the controller to the PostService. Services don't deal with the request, browser, or something else, a Service should take some data, transform it, and return a response.

Comment: @Victor Thank you for comments! In my understanding the controller get and validate the request. Then i pass the formData to the PostSerivce and not the request at all. Only the bodydata. So you think it's good to keep the business logic in the controller, right?

Comment: Yes, I think the controller should call all the services, and I think you should send to the service parameters instead of form data, Why? - Think about when it comes to creating test for that service, or reusing it in another controller that receives different request

Comment: @Victor I think I had expressed myself wrongly. In the controller I validate the data and then I send it with `$service->createPost($request->all()['data']);`. So I send an array and not a request object. In the test, I can build an array that is the same as the form and pass this array to the service method in the test. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Well, If new developers come to the project it won't be clear what the `$array` sent to `$service->createPost($array)` function should look like, I mean, if there would be `$service->createPost($title, $content, $publish_date)` it would be easier to maintain

Comment: @Victor I totally agree with you on that. But in my case, that would be the repository I call from the service. So `$repository->createPost($title, $content, $publish_date)`. What do you think? BTW: I find it really interesting to talk to you about this! Max